# Unit Test Event Handler

Tags: c#, events, testing, handler

I got this event handle and how can I do unit test for this

```
public class MyLearningEvent
{
    private event EventHandler _Closed;

    public event EventHandler Closed
    {
        add
        {
            _Closed -= value;
            _Closed += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            _Closed -= value;
        }
    }

    public void OnClosed()
    {
        if (_Closed != null) _Closed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Just modified code so that much clear

Thanks

Comment: That is C#.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea(v=vs.71).aspx, example 3,

Comment: Yes I know but I am new to event handler and I don't know how to execute the code in the remove part e.g. how to write code so that during debug the go topp remove {_Closed -=value}

Answer (score 3):

You should not unit test that code. It's a feature which is built into .NET. Your event handling is flawed imho.

```
add
{
    _Closed -= value;
    _Closed += value;
}
```

Probably means that your invokers don't keep track on if they have subscribed or not. That can lead to memory leaks: http://blog.naviso.fr/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/MemoryLeaks-English.jpg

A more robust (and thread safe implementation) is:

```
public class MyLearningEvent
{
    public event EventHandler Closed = delegate {};

    public void TriggerClosed()
    {
        Closed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

But you should not let anyone else trigger that event (make the `TriggerClosed` private/protected)

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.  This assumes `MyClass.Close()` raises the `MyClass.Closed` event.

```
public void ClosedEventHandlerIsNotCalledAfterBeingRemoved()
{
    MyLearningEvent Target = new MyLearningEvent();
    EventHandler Target_Closed = new EventHandler((sender, e) => { Assert.Fail("Closed EventHandler was raised after being removed."); });
    Target.Closed += Target_Closed;
    Target.Closed -= Target_Closed;
    Target.OnClosed();
}
```

Comment: I've modified code so it is more clear. Actually I like to have a unit test that cover the eventhandler Closed caused every time I tried to run the code with NCover, the code never get into the remove part e.g. remove
        {
            _Closed -= value;
        }

Comment: I copy and pasted your class into my code and put a breakpoint inside `Closed remove`.  The breakpoint triggered after the test method called `Target.Closed -= Target_Closed;`.  The `Closed remove` code is being run.